# How to deal with fast actions

Tags: javascript, cypress, bootstrap-table, end-to-end

I have a table showing the results of a query.
When I launch the query, a loading spinner is shown and then, when the server returns data, the results.
This simple scenario is weirdly tricky to test in Cypress.

```
cy.get("table .loadingSpinner", {timeout: 60000}).should("be.visible");
cy.get("table .loadingSpinner", {timeout: 60000}).should("be.not.visible");
cy.get("table", {timeout: 60000}).find("tr[data-index]", {timeout: 60000}).should("have.length.gt", 0);
```

Sometimes this code fails on the first line because the loading is so fast Cypress can't catch the visibility of the loading spinner. Worst of all, this scenario is making my test results depending on the server load.
Obviously, I can't just check if `table tr` has length > 0, it would match the previous data shown in the table, not the query I've just made and I want to check the results of.
How to deal with this?

I could wait for the raw server response, but that wouldn't be practical and maybe not even possible, I have dozens of tables querying different endpoints, sometimes more than one for the same table.

Comment: How do you launch the query? By api request in the test code or by UI action like `click`?

Comment: @RosenMihaylov how would the app know to show the spinner if the query came from`cy.request()`?

Comment: @RosenMihaylov the latter.. It is on a `click` action

Comment: @Richard Matsen May be it is just the app I am testing, but my developer colleagues tell me that a good application code will always trigger the spinner even for a part of the second since it is an async action. And cypress will catch and register it even if not shown on the screen. But it really depends on the code of the app.

Comment: @alfredopacino Then your idea is the same as mine - click => waitVisible => waitNotVisible. Though I think your selector is wrong. Usually loaders are modals that pop up on top of elements, not as part of the element. Check if you remove the `table` part of the loader selector if it will change the test behaviour and ask your development team how to select it that doesn`t help..

Comment: Rosen, thats a good thing to check, but be aware of spinners created with CSS animation, [examples](https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing the functionality of the spinner, or are you testing the result of the query?

If you are testing for the query, just do

```
{
  cy.wait(100)
  cy.get("table .loadingSpinner", {timeout: 60000}).should("be.not.visible");
}
```

And don't look for it to be there, just look for it not to be there. Increase timeout as needed.

If you are testing the spinner, then the application needs to slow down so that you have a chance to catch it.

Comment: I'm testing the results. Since `cy.wait` is a kind of bad practice, I would expect there is a way to avoid it in such a simple use case.

Comment: Looks like a good idea, 100ms is not a long wait. I was going to suggest adding an intercept with a delay, but this is simpler.

Comment: Yeah, this is where best practice meets reality. That 100ms wait is not going to kill your test suite. You won't notice it. It does the job. Obviously you don't want waits if you don't need them but sometimes it's unavoidable to put them in unless the developer are tailoring the app to the tests.

Comment: @ArildAndreassen you're right about best practice vs reality :). Also, it seems it solves the issue. And I prefer this over spying on the remote request, as I said sometimes there is more than one per table. It is a bit annoying though such a simple use case needs a workaround..

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see to reliably test the loader is to intercept and delay the response.

See [intercept - StaticResponseObject](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#StaticResponse-objects) which has a delay option to simulate a slow network, which is the scenario where the user sees the loader.

```js
{
  /**
   * Serve a fixture as the response body.
   */
  fixture?: string
  /**
   * Serve a static string/JSON object as the response body.
   */
  body?: string | object | object[]
  /**
   * HTTP headers to accompany the response.
   * @default {}
   */
  headers?: { [key: string]: string }
  /**
   * The HTTP status code to send.
   * @default 200
   */
  statusCode?: number
  /**
   * If 'forceNetworkError' is truthy, Cypress will destroy the browser connection
   * and send no response. Useful for simulating a server that is not reachable.
   * Must not be set in combination with other options.
   */
  forceNetworkError?: boolean
  /**
   * Milliseconds to delay before the response is sent.
   */
  delay?: number
  /**
   * Kilobits per second to send 'body'.
   */
  throttleKbps?: number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.should("not.be.empty")` on the table?

Comment: There is always something in the table. During the loading there is an hidden `<td>` with a message "No results" (bootstrap-table).

Comment: Frustrating. Is it possible to ignore the spinner altogether? You could maybe capture the state of the table prior to the query, execute the query, and then assert that the table has changed?

Comment: that would be a bit intricate and not an ideal solution. I need to rely somehow on the "loading" state. Think about the following case: I have 0 results, I launch another query and I get 0 results again. In this case, the DOM content of the tag `<table>` never changes, and of course I need better control than that during a test.